# Finding a point on a graph

Tags: excel, function, vba, graph

ok so I have a graph that has a steady increasing slope, much like an exponential graph. It then hits a point where the slope changes to a steep line, much steeper than a y=x graph. My question is, how do I find the point where the slope changes, whether it's VBA or just a function graph, I don't care, I just have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A point by itself does not say anything; but with respect to all the surrounding points. Thus, what you need to do is analysing a group of points to determine which ones are under certain conditions. You shouldn't be looking at the graph, but at its source: the data. What you want is an algorithm to perform certain geometrical analysis of a set of points.

Here you have a [post you will find useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112630/determine-where-line-slope-changes-algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like calculus. You might want to look into tangent lines
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Tangents_Rates.aspx